# Crystal - method on class destruction

Tags: database, destroy, crystal-lang

Is there a class method that is called when it is destroyed ?

When using `new`on a class, the `initialize` method is called, is there a `destroy`equivalent ?
I need to ensure a database is closed correctly among other things when the class is not used anymore ( the programm keeps running after the database is closed ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Object#finalize](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/finalize.html), however such a destructor should generally only be required for low-level abstractions like freeing resources from a C library. For normal app or library code I'd consider this a code smell and there are usually better solutions.

If the database connection is only used for a specific interaction, it is probably better to manually open and close (perhaps wrapped in a block) the connection instead of relying on a GC destructor hook.